# Android design support CollapsingToolbar subtitle

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

Is there any way to set a subtitle to a design support CollapsingToolbar?
I didn't find any method to do that, but I know the AppCompat Toolbar has a method to set subtitles, but trying to use that together with the CollapsingToolbar doesn't display anything.

Apps like Whatsapp also have a subtitle in a collaping toolbar even though they are probably not using the design support one, so I find it strange the design support one doesn't include that option.

My layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: Have you found out how to do it? Only workaround I can think about is to put a line break and set the bottom text to be smaller...

Comment: @androiddeveloper No, unfortunately I didn't. Only method that would work I think is to put two TextViews inside the toolbar and use them as title and subtitle, but I can't be bothered to do that :P

Comment: Sadly, I don't think what I wrote works. Would what you wrote work, so that when scrolling, the textViews would move up and down?

Comment: I think there are attributes to tell the Views how far they have to move and how much they will resize, but I didn't look into it that much so I am not able to provide you more informations about this, sorry

Comment: They say I can change the title appearance here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html , but the real attributes are collapsedTitleTextAppearance and expandedTitleTextAppearance . I tried changing the style. It worked, but for some reason it still doesn't change the fact that it has only one line. About what you wrote, I can't find any such attributes.

Comment: I think your best bet is to create a new question and describe your problem there, as I am not able to help you with this and you are more likely to get an answer by creating a new thread

Comment: Yes, here it is:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/33524056/878126

Comment: And after so much work on creating it, seems like it's a duplicate. I think this solution works nicely: https://github.com/harcoPro/SubtitleCoordinatorLayoutExample